# The Power of this Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algorithms

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\0&t&1-t\\-t-1&2t+1&1-t
\end{bmatrix}$$ and I would like to compute $A^k$ in $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]/\langle t^2+t+1\rangle$ (this means that $t^2+t+1=0$) for an arbitrary positive integer $k$.

I will be interested in both the result of this particular $A^k$ and how to compute such expressions in general:

Given a polynomial $p(t)$ of small degree (say $2$ or $3$), is there a reasonable algorithm to compute $A^k$ in $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]/\langle p(t)\rangle$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are in $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]/\langle p(t)\rangle$?

Comment: @Masacroso, would you please provide more details?

Comment: this must be similar to the power of a triangular matrix. There are some papers about that, check by example [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6820.pdf)